# Mysql errors 2014 or 1305 trying to call user-defined function in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I cannot access my user-defined function strip_punctuation() within my subsequent sql query. I'm using PHP and PDO.

I keep getting one of two errors no matter how I attempt this:

> MySQL error 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries
>   are active

OR

> MySQL error 1305 Function does not exists.

I've tried using prepare(), exec() and various other combinations, but no matter what I do I either get empty results or one of the two errors above.

Here is my function

(Note: $this->PROJECT_DB->connection-> is equivalent to PDO->connection->)

```
public function searchAutoComplete($searchString){
    $this->PROJECT_DB->connection->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);

    $sql ="DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS strip_punctuation; 
    DELIMITER | CREATE FUNCTION strip_punctuation($input text) RETURNS text 
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE $stringValue VARCHAR(100); 
    SET $stringValue = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE($input,'.',''),',',''),'?',''),'@',''),'#',''),'$',''),'%',''),'^',''),'*',''),'<',''),'>',''),':',''),'\n',''),')','');
    RETURN $stringValue;
    END; | DELIMITER ;";

    //$query = $this->PROJECT_DB->connection->exec($sql);
    $query = $this->PROJECT_DB->connection->query($sql);

    if($query===false){
        throw new Exception('Project.model: searchAutoComplete: Error with strip_punctiation function. Error was: ' . print_r($this->PROJECT_DB->connection->errorInfo(),true) . ';<br />SQL was: <br />' . $sql); 
    }

    $sql=" SELECT strip_punctuation('something@else.com') AS FoundWord;";

    $query = $this->PROJECT_DB->connection->query($sql);



    if($query===false){
        throw new Exception('Project.model: searchAutoComplete: Error with select query. Error was: ' . print_r($this->PROJECT_DB->connection->errorInfo(),true) . ';<br />SQL was: <br />' . $sql); 
    }
    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $results;
}
```

When I run both queries (defining the function and the simple select statement) in Sequel Pro (a sql editor program), I have no problems.
I've tried running both statements in one query and I get no results returned.

I'm running PHP 5.3.29 with pdo_mysql 5.5.40-36.1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function is well defined (because you did test it), the 2014 error is caused by attempting to run a query before fetching the results of an earlier query. You have to invoke PDO's fetch method *after* defining the function as well, to fetch MySQL's response.

TL;DR: Just add

```
$query->fetchAll();
```

after your first query, that should do the trick.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but I still get the 2014 error: Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). I've also tried a very simplified user-defined function as well. Very odd, because it was actually working before, with no fetchAll and no setting of MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY. I'm beginning to think it is something about the PDO installation.